Building and creating archive using swift xcode
**I tried to built an iOS application I was trying to upload it on testflight but i got this error and it's not working properly
**
SDK does not contain 'libarclite' at the path '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/arc/libarclite_iphonesimulator.a'; try increasing the minimum deployment target


Tried every solution like upgrading pod and installing pod and checking file if that file is exist in the folder

Does this help?

I think something like this on my project
If your project have multiple targets, try to set minimum deployment target for all targets you have to same for example iOS 13
